# Display updated image on scrollview after cropping

Tags: ios, swift

In one view, I have selected some images and on the click of a 'Done' button, I pass these images to another view (which is a scroll view) and also navigate to that view.

In the `viewDidLoad` of that scroll view I add the images to the scroll view like so...

```
for i in 0..<images.count {
  let imageView = UIImageView()
  let x = self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
  imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
  imageView.image = images[i]

  scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
  scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

  let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

  let cropButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Crop", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.crop))
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cropButton
}
```

Now, at the top of this scroll view there's a button called 'CROP' on the click of which I navigate to a certain view which is an interface for cropping (this interface is part of a library which crops images). Now after cropping the image, i click on a 'Done' button in that interface which results in the call of this function (part of that library itself)...

This function gives me the cropped image..

```
  func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
     print(image) --> This gives the cropped image

}
```

When the done button on the cropping interface is clicked, I go back to the scrollview again. To get the updated image i.e. the cropped image in the scrollview, I tried something like so....

```
    func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {

     croppedImage = image
    self.images[Int(currentPage)] = image // currentPage is the current index of scrollview 


    //Below lines of code are the same lines written in viewDidLoad
       for i in 0..<images.count {
          let imageView = UIImageView()
          let x = self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
          imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
          imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
          imageView.image =  self.images[i]

          scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
          scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

          let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
          navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

          let cropButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Crop", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.crop))
          navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cropButton
        }

    }
```

Now this does give me the updated image in the scrollview. But the issue is the scrollview starts from the very first image(i.e. on click of the Done button on the cropping interface, I land on the first image in the list of images in the scrollview). But I want to land on the very image that was cropped/updated.

What changes can I make to achieve that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you updated the scrollview with edited image, change the content offset of scrollview with respect to the `currentPage` at the end of `cropViewController:` method,

```
let xPosition = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(currentPage) //or currentPage + 1 depends on your currentPage logic
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0), animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Akhilrajtr..:)